# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 + SQL Server 2012 database compatibility level

Tags: sql-server-2012, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I know that Microsoft CRM 2011 is [compatible](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669061) with SQL Server 2012 since UR6 (UR10 for SP1).

According to [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699753.aspx):

> During an upgrade or a new installation, Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server
>   Setup sets the database **compatibility level to 100**, which is the
>   compatibility level of Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I'd like to know if "SQL Server 2012 compatible" means that I can bump the **compatibility level to 110**.

Comment: Documentation I was referring to is a bit old and assumes new installations will be on SQL Server 2008. Will a new new installation on SQL Server 2012 still set the compatibility level to 100?

Comment: IF CRM sets the compatibility level to 100 why would you want to set it to 110?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas I do not know for 100% certain, I would be hesitant to assume that you can.  If the installer sets it to that it's probably going to be best to leave it.  You could test it in a lab environment to confirm for your own needs, but it might be that you put yourself in a non-supported environment if you change it.

There are breaking changes in compatability level 110 as detailed [**here**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx#CurrentVersion).  Some of those could very well affect CRM.